# SSL client (soapUI) isn't responding with a certificate to the servers CertificateRequest

Tags: ssl, soapui, bouncycastle, keystore, jks

I'm trying to test a webservice using soapUI. The first step is setting up an secured connection. When I use a normal Java Keystore(JKS) everything works alright. However, when I convert the keystore to a bouncycastle keystore, I get the following error message: `[failed to extract any certificates or private keys - maybe bad password?]`

I'm sure I entered the correct password, so i'm wondering is soapUI doesn't support bouncycastle keystores for ssl connections? I already tried adding the bouncycastle security provider statically to the 'java.security' file.

Is there anyway to use bks with soapUI, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: When I'm monitoring the ssl handshake I confirmed that soapUI sends an empty message in respons to the 'CertificateRequest' from the server.

Answer (score 0):

I think only normal JKS is supported. If it works with JKS is there any need to convert to some other format?

Comment: First of all, thanks for answering. I was just testing with JKS to confirm my application is working. I'm going to work with Elliptic Curves with explicit parameters (not named curves), so I'll have to use a BKS since JKS doesn't support the EC with explicit parameters.